# Seleccionar registros de última hora con PHP en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, pdo

Tengo una aplicación web donde se pueden crear enlaces, y mi idea es hacer un **SELECT de la cantidad de enlaces que ha creado esa persona en la última hora**, para ver si ha superado el límite de X o no.

El caso es que no sé cómo hacer que seleccione solo los registros de la última hora.

Tengo una columna con la fecha en este formato `0000-00-00 00:00:00` con el valor de **TIMESTAMP** que coloca de forma automática cuándo se ha hecho el registro.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*******";
$password = "b*******";
$dbname = "*******";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM links WHERE user = ? AND date ...");
$stmt->bind_param($id);
$stmt->execute();

echo $stmt->num_rows;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla WHERE user = :user AND date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Comment: Gracias! Una cosa, estoy usando num_rows para obtener el número de filas y resulta que siempre me devuelve 0 (aunque quite todas las condiciones, es decir, no es por la fecha ni el usuario). Comparto todo el código, a ver si me puedes ayudar, por favor.

Comment: si utilizas `num_rows` dale un `select *` or select x campo no un `count(*)`!

Comment: He hecho "SELECT id FROM links", sin ninguna condición más, y me digue devolviendo 0... El nombre de la tabla es correcto y hay más de 500 registros. Saludos

Comment: te recomiendo que realices otra pregunta y coloques tu codigo!